# document.styleSheets removes Webkit specific CSS rules

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

Take a look at this [HTML, CSS and JavaScript](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ntxflpjy):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; 
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            html{
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.each(document.styleSheets, function () {
            var cssRules = this.cssRules;
            if (cssRules && cssRules.length && this.href === null) {
            var css = '';
            $.each(cssRules, function () {
              css += this.cssText;
            });
                document.write(css);
            }
        });
    })
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Basically, all it does is output the stylesheets in the current document read with JS through `document.styleSheets`.
Now, the problem: `document.styleSheets` does not contain Webkit specific styles. Instead, those styles are removed.
In my example `body` has `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;` but this rule is not output as you can see on the right.
Why is that?
And more importantly: How can I get that rule through `document.styleSheets`?

Comment: Your link contains no code (seems to be an error on the website). Anyway, put the code in your question.

Comment: @RGraham Weird - the link works for me, but I updated the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"text-size-adjust" [isn't supported by any non-mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust#Browser_compatibility), so if you're doing this on a desktop it's not appearing because the rule literally doesn't exist to the browser.

If you try your code with a supported rule (as below), you'll see the rule with the vendor prefix in your document.write()

```
body {
  -webkit-transition: all 4s ease;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```